# Solr query syntax Issue

Tags: solr

I'm trying to do the following query with Solr:

```
time:90000 OR (-time:[1521 TO *] AND -(time:[* TO 1519] OR time:[1521 TO *]))
```

it returns only one result with tag `time=90000`, but I have two items with tag `time` with value `90000` and `1520`. I would like them both.

Can anyone give me some explaination? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution: when I perform a negative query, I must write:

> `*:* -<query>`

For my issue, the solution is:

> `time:90000 OR (time:* -time:[1521 TO *] AND (time:* -(time:[* TO 1519] OR time:[1521 TO *])))`

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because negative queries are allowed at the top level only. See http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrQuerySyntax

```
Pure negative queries (all clauses prohibited) are allowed.
```

Try moving those negative queries out and post your findings here

Comment: If I try to perform:

    `-(time:[1521 TO *] OR (time:[* TO 1519] OR time:[1521 TO *]))`

The result is the item with `time=1520`

If I try this:

    `time:90000 OR -(time:[1521 TO *] OR (time:[* TO 1519] OR time:[1521 TO *]))`

I have no results...

Comment: Can you try this also time:90000 OR (-(time:[1521 TO *] OR (time:[* TO 1519] OR time:[1521 TO *])) <asterisk>:<asterisk> ) . Pls replace <asterisk> by *

Comment: Also include debugQuery=ON in your query. See http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters#debugQuery

Comment: I found the solution: when I perform a negative query, I must write: 
`*:* -<query>`

Comment: For my issue, the solution is: 
`time:90000 OR (time:* -time:[1521 TO *] AND (time:* -(time:[* TO 1519] OR time:[1521 TO *])))`